# Azure Search - Redundancy across regions

Tags: azure, search

It appears that Azure Search does not currently provide a facility that will allow me to configure back up across regions automatically.

Currently our back end product writes directly into the Azure index stored in a single region.  For redundancy purposes we want to ensure that the data is replicated in multiple regions.

I believe these are our choices:
1. Alter our upload process to replicate the data into different regions
2. Change the Azure Search index and implement an Indexer against an Azure Document DB.  It appears from my reading that Azure does provide an automated methodology of replicating data in a Document DB across regions.

Are there any other choices that I cannot seem to find?
For those of you with familiarity in this area - do you have any recommendations or things to watch out for?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: You're right, currently there's no ready to use way to automatically replicate data to multiple regions.